# Going from iterrows() to faster "nested -Pythonish- loops"

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm trying to evolve a piece of code from iterrows() to something faster, since I have a nested loop, the complexity is too big.

I found that apply and vectorization are better, but can't understand how to make that work for a nested loop.

Here's what I'm doing now.

```
clean = df.drop_duplicates(subset = "DESCRIPTION", keep = "first")
clean = clean.drop_duplicates(subset = "IMAGES", keep = "first")

##methode naive et un poil onereuse (n^2) pour ajouter les donnees extraites     
for index, crow in tqdm(clean.iterrows()):
for drow in df.iterrows():
    if crow["DESCRIPTION"] == drow[1]["DESCRIPTION"] or (crow["IMAGES"] == drow[1]["IMAGES"] and crow["IMAGES"] != []):
        if crow["CRAWL_SOURCE"] != drow[1]["CRAWL_SOURCE"] and crow["CRAWL_SOURCE"] not in drow[1]["CRAWL_SOURCE"]:
            clean.loc[index, "CRAWL_SOURCE"] = crow["CRAWL_SOURCE"] + " " + drow[1]["CRAWL_SOURCE"]
```

I'm deleting the duplicates and saving the clean dataset in the "clean" variable.
Since I still need to keep some data from the duplicates, I run a nested loop to get back what I need from the original df that is unchanged.

I'm new to Python so I might be doing this wrong, but I would like to vectorize this nested loop.

[image: Dataset example]
The green is the DESCRIPTION field, it is what creates duplicates.
The dataset "clean" doesn't have duplicates, it comes from the dataset "df".
The dataset "df" contains the doubles as well as the additionnal data they have.

What I want at the end is that the "clean" dataset contains the additionnal information that can be found in the "CRAWL_SOURCE" column of "df"
Like this:
[image: result]

The first line wasn't duplicated so it only has 1 value in yellow.
The second line had a duplicate, so I added the information.

Comment: Can you share sample for both DataFrame aswell as expected output ? Also can you explain what is your code doing ?

Comment: Did what I could, hope it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataframe "clean" origins from the dataframe "df" then you only need to drop the duplicates and have all Information.

```
df_clean = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["columnX", "columnY"], keep = "first").drop_duplicates(subset = "DESCRIPTION", keep = "first")
```

If that is not the case you can simply join or merge the Information you want to add itback, like this:

```
df_result = df_clean.reset_index().merge(df, on=["DESCRIPTION","CRAWL_SOURCE"], how="left").set_index("index")
```

Please note, that the "on=[]" Parameter Needs the list you want to match on.

Comment: It it close to the second solution, will work on it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your code, you want do have one line for every `IMAGE` with all the `CRAWL_SOURCE`s that matches either the `IMAGE` OR the `DESCRIPTION` that appears in one of the instances of this `IMAGE`, even if it's another `IMAGE`. If I got you wrong, comment and I'll delete this, but this is what I came up with (I know it's messy, and maybe someone would find a 'cleaner' way):

```
import itertools
df1 = df.groupby(['IMAGES']).agg(lambda x: list(x))['CRAWL_SOURCE'].reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION']).agg(lambda x: list(x))  
['CRAWL_SOURCE'].reset_index()
clean = df.merge(df1.rename({'CRAWL_SOURCE': 'CSI'}, axis=1), how='left').merge(df2.rename({'CRAWL_SOURCE': 'CSD'}, axis=1), how='left')
clean['CRAWL_SOURCE'] = clean['CSI'] + clean['CSD']
clean = clean.groupby(['IMAGES'])\
.agg(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)))))) 
['CRAWL_SOURCE'].reset_index()
```